# Layering in Visio and Presentation Problems?

Tags: microsoft-visio, presentations, flowchart

I am trying to make a flow chart in Visio, and I have multiple layers. Some broad and then they break down to more detailed layers. Is there a way to zoom out and only see the broad layers but as I zoom into a specific part on the chart I can see the smaller detailed layers?

Can visio do that? and If not how do you think I should go about using Visio to present this?